# Name of columns does not showing correctly

Tags: python, dataframe, average, stock

I have calculated fast moving average and slow moving average and the Adjusted closing price and want to display them together in a dataframe. Somehow all 3 of them shows "Adj Close". Can you help me check what is wrong with my code? Thanks heaps

```py
Adj_Close = data['Adj Close']

FastMA = 10
SlowMA = 50

FastMA = Adj_Close.rolling(window=FastMA).mean()
SlowMA = Adj_Close.rolling(window=SlowMA).mean()

datacolumns = [Adj_Close,FastMA,SlowMA]
df = pd.concat(datacolumns, axis = 1)


print (df)
```

Comment: `FastMA = Adj_Close.rolling(window=FastMA).mean().rename('FastMA')` and the same on slowMA

Answer (score 1):

Adj_Close is based on the column "Adj_Close" what you are doing is then to create 2 new variables containg the same column with the same name "Adj_Close". Then you modify the values of the series in both of those variables, but the name of the series is still the same. Therefore try:

```
FastMA = Adj_Close.rolling(window=FastMA).mean().rename("FastMA")
SlowMA = Adj_Close.rolling(window=SlowMA).mean().rename("SlowMA")
```

Example:

if you do this:

```
test_variable = df["column_name"]
test_variable = test_variable + 1
```

You would not expect the series to change its name, it is still "column_name". The same happens in your code. You do not rename the series, but instead you rename the variable containing the series which is named: "Adj_Close".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have modified the rolling windows as "FastWindow" and "SlowWindow" but still I would get the same result. How do I separate the calculation of FastMA and SlowMA as different variables? Thanks heaps

Comment: I am not sure what u mean, the first 2 code lines in my answer should fix the problem.